# Restriction of a covering map on a closed set having finite fibers is a proper map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, closed-map

> Let $p\colon X\to Y$ be a covering map between two connected
> topological manifolds. Let $C$ be a closed and path-connected
> subset of $X$ such that each fiber of the restriction map $p\big |C\to
>  Y$ is finite. Is $p\big|C\to Y$ a proper map?

I am trying to show $p$ is a closed map so that I can use this: [A continuous closed map defined on a Hausdorff space having compact fibers is a proper map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968571/a-characterization-of-proper-maps)

Also, note that [a finite-fold covering map is a closed map.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336827/why-must-a-finite-covering-map-be-closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: This is false even for the universal covering $p$ of the once-punctured plane and $C$ such that $p|_C$ is 1-1.